# Непослушный слайдер

Tags: html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

Слайдер не слушает команды, вместо одного слайда отображает все и сразу, не ясно как задает ширину, не могу найти причину. Заранее благодарен за любую помощь!
ЗЫ Slick-Slider ведёт себя так же

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="red" lang="ru">
<head>
    //= template/head.html
    <title>WEB-SITE!</title>
</head>
<body>

//= template/nav.html



<section class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="logo col-lg-2">
                <h4>Lotcar.ru</h4>
                <hr class="black">
                <p>8 (800) 555-35-35</p>
            </div>
            <div class="menu_black menu-activator offset-6 col-lg-4">
                <p>ПРЕИМУЩЕСТВА</p>
                <a href="#">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 56 56" style="enable-background:new 0 0 56 56;" xml:space="preserve" width="50px" height="50px">
                        <g>
                            <path d="M28,0C12.561,0,0,12.561,0,28s12.561,28,28,28s28-12.561,28-28S43.439,0,28,0z M28,54C13.663,54,2,42.336,2,28   S13.663,2,28,2s26,11.664,26,26S42.337,54,28,54z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                            <path d="M40,16H16c-0.553,0-1,0.448-1,1s0.447,1,1,1h24c0.553,0,1-0.448,1-1S40.553,16,40,16z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                            <path d="M40,27H16c-0.553,0-1,0.448-1,1s0.447,1,1,1h24c0.553,0,1-0.448,1-1S40.553,27,40,27z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                            <path d="M40,38H16c-0.553,0-1,0.448-1,1s0.447,1,1,1h24c0.553,0,1-0.448,1-1S40.553,38,40,38z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="clients">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slide">
                    <h2>Николай М.</h2>
                    <p>Таким образом укрепление
                        и развитие структуры позволяет
                        выполнять важные задания по
                        разработке системы обучения
                        кадров, соответствует насущным
                        потребностям. Равным образом
                        начало повседневной работы.
                        Таким образом укрепление
                        и развитие структуры позволяет
                        выполнять важные задания по
                        разработке системы обучения
                        кадров, соответствует насущным
                        потребностям. Равным образом
                        начало повседневной работы.
                        Таким образом укрепление
                        и развитие структуры позволяет
                        выполнять важные задания по
                        разработке системы обучения
                        кадров, соответствует насущным
                        потребностям. Равным образом
                        начало повседневной работы.
                        Таким образом укрепление
                        и развитие структуры позволяет
                        выполнять важные задания по
                        разработке системы обучения
                        кадров, соответствует насущным
                        потребностям. Равным образом
                        начало повседневной работы.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <h2>Николай М.</h2>
                    <p>Таким образом укрепление
                        и развитие структуры позволяет
                        выполнять важные задания по
                        разработке системы обучения
                        кадров, соответствует насущным
                        потребностям. Равным образом
                        начало повседневной работы.
                        Таким образом укрепление
                        и развитие структуры позволяет
                        выполнять важные задания по
                        разработке системы обучения
                        кадров, соответствует насущным
                        потребностям. Равным образом
                        начало повседневной работы.
                        Таким образом укрепление
                        и развитие структуры позволяет
                        выполнять важные задания по
                        разработке системы обучения
                        кадров, соответствует насущным
                        потребностям. Равным образом
                        начало повседневной работы.
                        Таким образом укрепление
                        и развитие структуры позволяет
                        выполнять важные задания по
                        разработке системы обучения
                        кадров, соответствует насущным
                        потребностям. Равным образом
                        начало повседневной работы.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <h2>Николай М.</h2>
                    <p>Таким образом укрепление
                        и развитие структуры позволяет
                        выполнять важные задания по
                        разработке системы обучения
                        кадров, соответствует насущным
                        потребностям. Равным образом
                        начало повседневной работы.
                        Таким образом укрепление
                        и развитие структуры позволяет
                        выполнять важные задания по
                        разработке системы обучения
                        кадров, соответствует насущным
                        потребностям. Равным образом
                        начало повседневной работы.
                        Таким образом укрепление
                        и развитие структуры позволяет
                        выполнять важные задания по
                        разработке системы обучения
                        кадров, соответствует насущным
                        потребностям. Равным образом
                        начало повседневной работы.
                        Таким образом укрепление
                        и развитие структуры позволяет
                        выполнять важные задания по
                        разработке системы обучения
                        кадров, соответствует насущным
                        потребностям. Равным образом
                        начало повседневной работы.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <a class="prev" href="#">назад</a>
                    <a class="prev" href="#">вперед</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<div class="shapes"></div>


//= template/footer.html
//= template/scripts.html

<script>
    $('.slider').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        nav:true,
        autoWidth:true,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1
            },
        }
    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
section.clients {
  margin: 200px 0 50px 0;
  h2 {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'GilroyB', sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    line-height: 0;
    margin-top: 30px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .25s;
  }
  p {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'GilroyB', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    transition: .25s;
    margin-top: 90px;
    opacity: 0;
    max-width: 75%;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
  }
  div.buttons {
    width: 15%;
    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    padding: 5px 0;
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 0 10px;
      font-size: 18px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-family: 'GilroyL', sans-serif;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
  }
}

.owl-item {
  display: inline;
}

.owl-stage {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
}
```

Консоль не выводит ошибок, в такие моменты особенно непросто установить причину

Comment: допиши диву с классом slider класс owl-carousel

Comment: Дополню, CSS файл, поставляемый вместе со слайдером, также должен быть подключен.